# Trying to create view in SQL server 2008r2 as provided

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

for the below diagram

[image]

As per the diagram I have two tables Table1 and Tabel2.
I'm trying to generate a VIEW which populates the values accordingly and also must accept null valus to the fields if any value doesn't present

Anyone please help me

Comment: If you know the exact number of columns you need you can use a pivot or a cross tab (also known as conditional aggregation). If you don't know how many columns you will need to use the dynamic version of these. If the number of columns varies you will NOT be able to do this in a view.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea to do this in sql. Usually it is better to write a simple join query and the do the pivoting within the user interface not the SQL.